# django forms ForeignKey 'value error must be an instance'

Tags: javascript, django, forms, radio-button, foreign-keys

I'm trying to port an application with an existing db.  I'm using db_column to have django model Foreign Keys correctly while using the existing database names and columns.

models.py

```
class foo(models.Model):
  foo_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
  foo_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
  foo_type_lookup = models.ForeignKey('foo_type_lookup', to_field="foo_type_id", db_column="foo_type", blank=True, null=True)

class foo_type_lookup(models.Model):
  foo_type_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
  foo_type = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, null=False)
```

The table foo_type_lookup has two rows (ids 0 and 1) for foo_type 'bar' and 'baz'.  I'm trying to make a form to add a record in the foo table which will have a foreign key to foo_type_lookup. Foo can either be bar or baz.

views.py

```
   def add_foo(request):
        action = '#'
        errors = None
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = FooForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():

                form.save(commit=True)

                return home(request)
            else:
                # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
                errors = form.errors
        else:
            # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
            form = FooForm()

        # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
        # Render the form with error messages (if any).
        return render(request, 'foo/add_foo.html', {'form' : form, 'errors' : errors, 'action' : action})
```

forms.py

```
CONTACT_FOO_CHOICES = [[0,'Bar'],[1,'Baz']]

class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    foo_type_lookup = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(), choices=CONTACT_FOO_CHOICES)
    foo_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=500, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = foo 

        fields = ('foo_name','foo_type_lookup')
```

I have to iterate over the form object in my template so I can add a jQuery function when the radio buttons are changed.  I find this pretty clunky, but I'm not sure of a more django way to accomplish this:

add_foo.html

```
<h2>add_foo.html</h2>
<form action="{{action}}" method="post" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.auto_id = 'id_foo_type_lookup' %}
           {% for choice in form.foo_type_lookup.field.choices %}
            <li>
              <label for="id_{{ field.html_name }}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                  <input type="radio"
                    id="id_{{ field.html_name }}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}"
                    value="{{ choice.0 }}"
                    {% if choice.0 == '0' %}
                      checked="true"
                    {% endif %}
                    name="{{ field.html_name }}"
                    onchange="someFunction('id_{{ field.html_name }}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}')"/>
                   {{ choice.1 }}
              </label>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        <div class="formfield_err">{{ field.help_text }}</div>
          <div id="{{ field.auto_id }}_container" >
              <div class="formfield_divlbl">{{ field.label_tag }}
              </div>
              <div class="formfield_divfld">{{ field }}
                  {% if field.field.required %}
                  <span class="required">*</span>
                  {% endif %}
              </div>
              <div id="{{ field.auto_id }}_errors">{{ field.errors }}
              </div>
          </div><div class="clear" style="margin-bottom:12px;"></div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I get the error:

Cannot assign "'0'": "foo.foo_type_lookup" must be a "foo_type_lookup" instance.

How do I layout the radio buttons for the type lookup to add onchange javascript and supply my ModelForm with an object of 'foo_type_lookup' so the data will save to the database?

Answer (score 1):

A `ChoiceField` does not know it needs to coerce the provided value to a particular model instance.

Use a `ModelChoiceField` instead.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Whoops, it seems you want some very specific display logic for your values hard coded into your python which may not necessarily equate to your string representations of your related model.

If so, override your form `save` to apply any coercion there before the real save gets called via `super`.

You can also manually apply any python logic via `commit=False` (I notice you already have that statement set to `True` and perhaps you were playing with the idea.)

```
obj = form.save(commit=false)
obj.foo_lookup_type = MyObject.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['foo_lookup_type'])
obj.save()
```